# How to install mod_rewrite on Ubuntu for Drupal 6

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, drupal

would anyone have some easy to follow step on how to install mod_rewrite on Ubuntu, its for Drupal 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is normally installed with the apache2 package, you only have to enable it:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: or you could do it from Synaptic too.

Comment: Thanks Christian, you are correct it is installed. but for whatever reason i still can not enable clean url's on drupal.  I will ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change virtual host option "AllowOverride" of your Drupal site to:

```
AllowOverride All
```